# Akka Streams - Choose alternative flow when backpressured

Tags: akka, akka-stream

With akka streams, I want to redirect my flow when the original flow becomes slower.

Basically, I have a lookup flow, which may return a value; if it fails, the stream uses the fetching flow.

But I also want to use the fetching flow when the consuming from lookup is backpressured.

It looks like this:

```
Lookup ~> Return
Lookup ~> Fetch ~> Return
Fetch ~> Return (when lookup is slow)
```

What would be the correct way to handle this? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look to some Partition Stage example http://ticofab.io/akka-stream-partition-example/.

Comment: This is ok, but my condition for alternative flow is "backpressure", which I don't know how to notice before sending data to the flow.

Comment: You need a custom GraphStage to achieve this that combines two flows. I think that your use case is similar to what Flow.expand does, so you should be able to get an idea from there.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.